# Which are the modern glTranslate and glRotate alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

Important edit: I am using the [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) binding of OpenGL
I am trying not to use the [`glRotate`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glRotate.html) and [`glTranslate`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glTranslate.html) functions, but I have not found any alternative to this two functions. This functions are deprecated. What can I use?

Comment: A [Shader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader) program and [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable(s) of type `mat4`. But probably this question is to broad.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I forgot to say I am using Python version of OpenGL

Comment: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.html

Comment: @MaxVollmer I have seen the link, where are the alternatives to the functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern way is to write a [Shader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader) program, to use [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) and to use [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable(s) of type `mat4`.
There is more code to write, in compare to the deprecated fixed function pipeline but the benefit is high flexibility and a far better performance, in compare to drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBegin.html) sequences.

For the matrix calculations can be used the [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) library, which is the python version of the c++ [OpenGL Mathematics (glm)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) library.

e.g. A scale, rotation matrix around the z-axis by an `angle` and translation can set by:

```py
model = glm.mat4(1)
model = glm.translate(model, glm.vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0))
model = glm.rotate(model, angle, glm.vec3(0, 0, 1))
model = glm.scale(model, glm.vec3(0.5, 0.5, 1))
```

In compare to the the [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) operation [`glRoatate`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glRotate.html), the angle has to be set in radians.
Note, instead of using PyGLM it is also possible to use the popular [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) library and [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), but PyGLM is closer to that what you know from Legacy OpenGL and the functions `glScale`, `glTranslate` and `glRotate`.
Of course it would be possible to set the the 4x4 matrices with out any library and to implement the matrix operations by yourself, too.

See the small example program, which uses [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) and [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) (beside the modules [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) and [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)):

```py
import math 
import ctypes
import glm 
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

class MyWindow:

    __caption = 'OpenGL Window'
    __vp_size = [800, 600]
    __vp_valid = False
    __glut_wnd = None

    __glsl_vert = """
        #version 450 core

        layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_pos;
        layout (location = 1) in vec4 a_col;

        out vec4 v_color;

        layout (location = 0) uniform mat4 u_proj; 
        layout (location = 1) uniform mat4 u_view; 
        layout (location = 2) uniform mat4 u_model; 

        void main()
        {
            v_color     = a_col;
            gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * u_model * vec4(a_pos.xyz, 1.0);
        }
    """

    __glsl_frag = """
        #version 450 core

        out vec4 frag_color;
        in  vec4 v_color;

        void main()
        {
            frag_color = v_color;
        }
    """

    __program = None
    __vao = None
    __vbo = None

    def __init__(self, w, h):

        self.__vp_size = [w, h]

        glutInit()
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowSize(self.__vp_size[0], self.__vp_size[1])
        __glut_wnd = glutCreateWindow(self.__caption)

        self.__program = compileProgram( 
            compileShader( self.__glsl_vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER ),
            compileShader( self.__glsl_frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER ),
        )

        attribures = [
        #    x       y    z    R  G  B  A
            -0.866, -0.5, 0,   1, 0, 0, 1, 
             0.866, -0.5, 0,   1, 1, 0, 1,
             0,      1.0, 0,   0, 0, 1, 1
        ]
        vertex_attributes = (GLfloat * len(attribures))(*attribures)
        itemsize = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)

        self.__vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.__vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_attributes, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        self.__vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(self.__vao)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 7*itemsize, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 7*itemsize, ctypes.c_void_p(3*itemsize))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

        glUseProgram(self.__program)

        glutReshapeFunc(self.__reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.__mainloop)

    def run(self):
        self.__starttime = 0
        self.__starttime = self.elapsed_ms()
        glutMainLoop()

    def elapsed_ms(self):
      return glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - self.__starttime

    def __reshape(self, w, h):
        self.__vp_valid = False

    def __mainloop(self):

        if not self.__vp_valid:
            self.__vp_size = [glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)]
            self.__vp_valid = True
            glViewport(0, 0, self.__vp_size[0], self.__vp_size[1])

        proj  = glm.mat4(1)
        view  = glm.mat4(1)
        model = glm.mat4(1)

        aspect = self.__vp_size[0]/self.__vp_size[1]
        aspect_x = aspect if self.__vp_size[0] > self.__vp_size[1] else 1.0
        aspect_y = 1/aspect if self.__vp_size[0] < self.__vp_size[1] else 1.0 
        proj = glm.ortho(-aspect_x, aspect_x, -aspect_y, aspect_y, -1.0, 1.0)

        angle = self.elapsed_ms() * math.pi * 2 / 3000.0
        model = glm.translate(model, glm.vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0))
        model = glm.rotate(model, angle, glm.vec3(0, 0, 1))
        model = glm.scale(model, glm.vec3(0.5, 0.5, 1))

        glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(proj) )
        glUniformMatrix4fv(1, 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(view) )
        glUniformMatrix4fv(2, 1, GL_FALSE, glm.value_ptr(model) )

        glClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

        glutSwapBuffers()
        glutPostRedisplay()


window = MyWindow(800, 600)
window.run()
```

Comment: The script there outputs this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 130, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
  File "C:/(location)", line 107, in __mainloop
    proj  = glm.mat4(1)
AttributeError: module 'glm' has no attribute 'mat4'
GLUT Display callback <bound method MyWindow.__mainloop of <__main__.MyWindow object at 0x02AEFE70>> with (),{} failed: returning None module 'glm' has no attribute 'mat4'

Comment: do you use the module called "glm" or the module called "PyGLM"?

Comment: In the code above it is written "import glm", is it correct?

Comment: I dont know what is happening, I have installed PyGLM but I can not import it

Comment: It finally works, I have deleted the glm package, I only have installed the PyGLM package, maybe their names were overriding or something, thank you so much!

Comment: Can I use this mechanic without a glut window and without a shader program? It is quite complex. I am using a PyQT5 OpenGL widget, and I do not know how to implement it properly